# Unable to show tf state

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am list my tf state

```
✗ tf state list
module.cluster_build.data.google_project.project
module.cluster_build.google_compute_network_peering_routes_config.update_peering_config
module.cluster_build.google_container_cluster.build
module.cluster_build.google_project_iam_member.cluster_node_roles["roles/container.clusterViewer"]
module.cluster_build.google_project_iam_member.cluster_node_roles["roles/logging.logWriter"]
module.cluster_build.google_project_iam_member.cluster_node_roles["roles/monitoring.metricWriter"]
module.cluster_build.google_project_iam_member.cluster_node_roles["roles/monitoring.viewer"]
module.cluster_build.google_project_iam_member.cluster_node_roles["roles/stackdriver.resourceMetadata.writer"]
module.cluster_build.google_service_account.build
module.cluster_build.google_storage_bucket_iam_member.gcr_read
```

But if i want to see details, i cant and get an error

```
✗ tf state show module.cluster_build.google_container_cluster.build
unsupported attribute "instance_group_urls"
# module.cluster_build.google_container_cluster.build:
resource "google_container_cluster" "build" {
```

tf version being used

```
✗ tf --version
Terraform v1.0.10
on darwin_arm64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v4.0.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta v4.0.0
```

what might be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [release notes for 4.0.0 of the Google provider mention](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/releases/tag/v4.0.0), which got released 5 days ago (when I am writing this):

> container: instance_group_urls has been removed in favor of node_pool.managed_instance_group_urls (#10442)

So:

- I guess you might've upgraded the Terraform provider version recently and your code became invalid with regards to the new version...
- ... and another guess is that `terraform state list` doesn't call refresh or doesn't trigger provider activity in any way (I am not sure about that), thus it continues to work